# Publish messages from default eventbus to SNS topic cross-account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I want to route specific events with event-rule from the default eventbus in account A to an SNS topic in account B.

Got this to work when both the eventbus and the topic was in the same account but started to encounter issues when the SNS topic was moved to another account.

I'm using CDK v2 in python and have one glue job, where I use `job.on_failure(<ITopic>)`
But when I instead setup the SNS topic in the other account and imported that topic into the stack and passed it to the function as before, I encounter the following error when trying to deploy:

```
stack failed: Error: The stack named <stack-name> failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Access to the resource arn:aws:sns:<accountB-region>:<accountB>:<topic-name> is denied. Reason: Adding cross-account target is not permitted.
```

I have tried to add access policy to the SNS topic in account B as:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::<Account A>:root",
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "sns:Publish",
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:<accountB-region>:<accountB>:<topic-name>"
    }
  ]
}
```

But still encountering the same issue.

Did even try with Condition on aws:PrincipalOrgID and AWS:SourceAccount in the policy without success.

My second approach was to create IAM Role in Account B with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:<accountB-region>:<accountB>:<topic-name>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

And that has the following trust relationships:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account A>:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then trying to add that to the eventbus policy in cdk as:

```
event_bus_policy = aws_events.EventBusPolicy(
            self, 
            "MyTestBusPolicy",
            event_bus=default_eventbus,
            statement=iam_.PolicyStatement(
                effect=iam_.Effect.ALLOW,
                actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
                principals=[iam_.ServicePrincipal("events.amazonaws.com")],
                resources=["arn:aws:iam::<account B>:role/<role-name>"],
            ),
            statement_id="test-statement"
        )
```

I have tries different approaches for the principal AccountPrincipal(<account A>)
But both that and the one above results in the following error when deploying:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Unable to resolve object tree with circular reference. Path: /Resources/${Token[<stack>.MyTestBusPolicy.Resource.LogicalID.2070]}/Properties/statement/_principals/array/0/grantPrincipal/grantPrincipal/grantPrincipal/grantPrincipal/grantPrincipal/grantPrincipal/grantPrincipal/grantPrincipal/grantPrincipal..
```

I have also tried to leave out the Principal part but that results in:

```
failed: Error: The stack named <stack-name> failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Unknown field _principal (Service: AWSEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
```

The expected result is to be able to route events from default eventbus to SNS topic cross-account. Don't know where I'm getting this wrong or if this is even possible?

I think a workaround would be:

1. eventbus (Account A) -> eventbus (Account B) -> SNS topic (Account B).
2. eventbus (Account A) -> SNS (Account A) -> Lambda (Account A) -> SNS (Account B).

But I would like to be able to publish directly to the SNS topic, because it will be used as an shared alert topic between many accounts.

I would be glad to hear if there is any other approaches.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible stack that produces the error?